# I want to keep the active category style even if the active category link is followed by another link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wrote the category code referring to the answers in other questions.
So I succeeded to apply the style to the link that was activated when the category link was clicked.
But if you turn the page like page 2 or page 3 on the active category page, the style will disappear.

I want the style to be maintained no matter what additional links are attached after the active category link.
Please help me.

I didn't speak English, so I used a translator.
So the sentence may not be smooth.
Sorry..!

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = window.location;
        $('.cateBox li a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
        $('.cateBox li a').filter(function() {
            return this.href == url;
        }).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .cateBox {
        position: relative;
    }

    .cateBox:after {
        display: block;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }

    .cateBox li {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 180px;
        height: 34px;
        float: left;
        line-height: 34px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .cateBox li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .cateBox li:hover {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .cateBox li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .cateBox li.active {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .cateBox li.active a {
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>

<div id="nav">
    <ul class="cateBox">
        <li><a href="index.html">MAIN</a></li>
        <li><a href="sub01.html">SUB01</a></li>
        <li><a href="sub02.html">SUB02</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .cateBox {
        position: relative;
    }

    .cateBox:after {
        display: block;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }

    .cateBox li {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 180px;
        height: 34px;
        float: left;
        line-height: 34px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .cateBox li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .cateBox li:hover {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .cateBox li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .cateBox li.active {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .cateBox li.active a {
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>

<div id="nav">
    <ul class="cateBox">
        <li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">MAIN</a></li>
        <li><a href="sub01.html" target="_blank">SUB01</a></li>
        <li><a href="sub02.html" target="_blank">SUB02</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```